# UpdateColumns triggers Gorm hook with incorrect values

Tags: postgresql, go, go-gorm

I have this code which updates the `upvote` and `downvote` columns in my table:

```golang
// tx is my transaction

// `content.model` is a model interface

// `content.id` is the ID of what I'm going for

// `columnUpdates` is a `columnUpdates := make(map[string]interface{})` with 
// a bunch of different updates to the upvote & downvote columns

...

query := tx.Model(content.model).
    Where("id = ?", content.id).
    UpdateColumns(columnUpdates)
if err := query.Error; err != nil {
    tx.Rollback()
    return err
}
```

...which in turn triggers this Gorm hook (checked, it does trigger it):

```golang
func (p *Post) AfterUpdate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    fmt.Println("upvotes: ", p.Upvote)
    fmt.Println("downvotes: ", p.Downvote)
    p.VoteScore = int(p.Upvote) - int(p.Downvote)
    return nil
}
```

but the hook always prints both votes as 0 even though they are not 0.

My goal is to have `upvote` and `downvote` fields inside my postgres table and a `vote_score` field that is auto-updated upon a row's `upvote`/`downvote` being updated. However, `vote_score` won't be calculated properly if `upvote` and `downvote` are always 0 in the hook.

How can I get the correct vote values in the Gorm Hook?

Here is my `Post` struct model, with just the relevant fields shown:

```golang
type Post struct {
    Downvote      uint         `gorm:"column:downvote"`
    Upvote        uint         `gorm:"column:upvote"`
    VoteScore     int          `gorm:"column:vote_score"`
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: [Without-Hooks-x2F-Time-Tracking](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Without-Hooks-x2F-Time-Tracking)

Comment: And method `Model` arg should be an pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I've just looked at your code and I found out a couple of issues. First, let me present my working code, then, I'm gonna walk you through the changes.

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Post struct {
    ID        int
    Downvote  uint `gorm:"column:downvote"`
    Upvote    uint `gorm:"column:upvote"`
    VoteScore int  `gorm:"column:vote_score"`
}

func (p *Post) AfterUpdate(tx *gorm.DB) error {
    fmt.Println("upvotes: ", p.Upvote)
    fmt.Println("downvotes: ", p.Downvote)
    p.VoteScore = int(p.Upvote) - int(p.Downvote)
    if err := tx.Model(&Post{}).Where("id = ?", p.ID).UpdateColumn("vote_score", p.VoteScore).Error; err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost port=54322 user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn))
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&Post{})

    // db.Create(&Post{ID: 1})

    if err := db.Model(&Post{ID: 1}).Where("id = ?", 1).Updates(map[string]interface{}{"upvote": 4, "downvote": 3}).Error; err != nil {
        db.Rollback()
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        return
    }
}
```

The first issue is the usage of the method `UpdateColumns`. The latter must be used when you want neither the time tracking nor the hooks to be triggered. You can find more in this section of the `GORM` documentation: [link](https://gorm.io/docs/update.html#Without-Hooks-x2F-Time-Tracking).
After adding the `ID` to the struct, I make sure that the correct `ID` was set in the `AfterUpdate` hook. Thanks to this you can re-run an update to edit the just updated record.

*If you don't want to run two updates you might use another hook that runs before the update.*

Let me know if this solves your issue, thanks!

Comment: The hook still only ever receives the upvote/downvote values as 0 and 0. Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: EDIT: I fixed the hook issue by just not using hooks... I ended up just making another Update call inside the body of my handler :)

Comment: my code should work if you want to dive deep into the error, you can update the question's code and I'll check. Thanks